# Basic neural network in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to implement a very basic neural network in TensorFlow but I am having some problems. It is a very basic network that takes as input to values (hours or sleep and hours of study) and predicts the score on a test (I found this example on you-tube). So basically I have only one hidden layer with three units, each one computes an activation function (sigmoid) and the cost function is sum of square errors and I am using Gradient descent to minimize it. So the problem is, when I train the net with the training data and try to make some predictions using the same training data, the results do not quite match and they also appear strange because the look equal each other.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import input_data

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# create a 2-D version of input for plotting
trX = np.matrix(([3,5], [5,1],[10,2]), dtype=float)
trY = np.matrix(([85], [82], [93]), dtype=float) # 3X1 matrix
trX = trX / np.max(trX, axis=0)
trY = trY / 100 # 100 is the maximum score allowed

teX = np.matrix(([3,5]), dtype=float)
teY = np.matrix(([85]), dtype=float)
teX = teX/np.amax(teX, axis=0)
teY = teY/100

def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01))

def model(X, w_h, w_o):
    z2 = tf.matmul(X, w_h)
    a2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z2) # this is a basic mlp, think 2 stacked logistic regressions
    z3 = tf.matmul(a2, w_o)
    yHat = tf.nn.sigmoid(z3)
    return yHat # note that we dont take the softmax at the end because our cost fn does that for us

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 2])
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 1])

W1 = init_weights([2, 3]) # create symbolic variables
W2 = init_weights([3, 1])

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

py_x = model(X, W1, W2)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(py_x - Y))
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cost) # construct an optimizer
predict_op = py_x

sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX, Y: trY})

print sess.run(predict_op, feed_dict={X: trX})

sess.close()
```

It yields:

> [[ 0.51873487]
>    [ 0.51874501]
>    [ 0.51873082]]

and I believe it should be similar to the training data results.

I am quite new to neural nets and machine learning so pardon me for any mistakes, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main reason that your network isn't training is that the statement:

```
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: trX, Y: trY})
```

…only executes once. In TensorFlow, running `train_op` (or whatever operation is returned from `Optimizer.minimize()` will only cause the network to take a single gradient descent step. You should execute it in a loop to perform iterative training, and the weights will eventually converge.

Two other tips: (i) you might achieve faster convergence if you feed a *subset* of your training data in each step, rather than the entire dataset; and (ii) the learning rate of 0.5 is probably too high (although this depends on the data).

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I put the training step in a loop and tried many combinations of loop sizes and while indeed the scores got a closer to the training data, it did not quite converge. Even trying to over fit model the maximum I could get was:
[[ 0.85000151]
 [ 0.85349745]
 [ 0.89352685]]

Comment: @Thalles, I am very green on this as well, but I can tell you there are two ways to train your nnet: online or stochastic learning, where backpropagation learns from each observation alone, and batch learning where it learns from all at the same time. There is also mini-batch which is a mix of both. Stochastic tends to be faster, but convergence goes all over the place. Batch tends to be slower, but convergence is more steady. Do you know which one is being used?

Comment: @Thalles you will never get 100% accuracy, but your model could be much better if it included for instance biases terms.